# How to print a dashed box with the letter Q in it?

Tags: python

I was trying this problem in Python. I am unable to get the desired output. The problem is to print 'Q' in a dashed box. Here is my code:

```
def printBoard (board):
    for row in range(0, len(board)):
        for col in range(0, len(board)):
            if board[row][col]:
                print('  Q  ', end = '')
            else:
                print('  | ', end = '')
        print('\n')
```

My output :

```
 Board size = 4

 |  |  Q |

 Q |  |  |

 |  |  |  Q

 |  Q |  |
```

Expected  output:

```
Board size = 4
 -----------------------
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |  Q  |     |
|     |     |     |     |
 -----------------------
|     |     |     |     |
|  Q  |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
 -----------------------
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |  Q  |
|     |     |     |     |
 -----------------------
|     |     |     |     |
|     |  Q  |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
 -----------------------
```

Comment: A box has two vertical walls whether there's a Q in it or not; right now you're not printing a wall if there's a Q. You also aren't printing your horizontal walls anywhere, or the vertical parts that extend above and below the lines with a Q.

Comment: @mukhtar ali what does the array board hold?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to draw board for n queens problem. Can you give the value for variable `board` you passed to function?

Comment: @thisisjaymehta iam trying to draw the n queen borad the size of board is 8

Comment: Ok. But can you tell what `board` variable hold? Just print the value of board somewhere and show us the output.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your board variable contains a list which specify the position of queens on board like:

```
board = [[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0]]
```

Here is python code which will print your board:

```py
def horizontal_line(i):
    print(" " + "-" * (len(i)*6-1) + " ")

def horizontal_space(i):
    print("|" + "     |" * (len(i)))

def horizontal_value(i):
    print("|", end="")
    for j in i:
        print("  Q  |", end="") if j == 1 else print("     |", end="")
    print()

def printBoard(board):
    horizontal_line(board)
    for i in board:
        horizontal_space(i)
        horizontal_value(i)
        horizontal_space(i)
        horizontal_line(i)

printBoard(board)
```

Output:

```
 ----------------------- 
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |  Q  |     |
|     |     |     |     |
 ----------------------- 
|     |     |     |     |
|  Q  |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
 ----------------------- 
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |  Q  |
|     |     |     |     |
 ----------------------- 
|     |     |     |     |
|     |  Q  |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
 -----------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tabulate` module

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
board = [[None, None, 1, None], [1, None, None, None], [None, None, None, 1], [None, 1, None, None]]
board = [['Q' if ele == 1 else None for ele in row] for row in board]

print(tabulate(board, tablefmt="grid"))
```

**Output:**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | Q |   |
+---+---+---+---+
| Q |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | Q |
+---+---+---+---+
|   | Q |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: actually this is the n queen problem so the position of q depends on the random value that places it  on the board. this method didn't work for me as iam executing it on putty which dont have tabulate module in it

Answer (score 0):

The point of the OP's question was not to literally print out the boxes with Q's at the exact positions in the example...

An implementation that allows placing Q's in the boxes at runtime, and randomly populating the boxes.

This code should work on both Python3 and Python2.

```
>>> from random import sample
>>>
>>> def board(x, y):
...     b = (('+' + '---+' * x + '\n') +
...         (('|' + ' . |' * x + '\n') +
...          ('+' + '---+' * x + '\n')) * y)
...     return list(b)
...     
>>> def print_board(board):
...     print(''.join(board))
...     
>>> board_array = board(4, 4) # Generate a 4x4 game board.
>>> 
>>> # Lists below have the positions to place the Q's at. 
>>> # pos1d is a 1-dimension flat list of positions; pos2d, a 2-dim list.
>>> pos1d = tuple(i for i, ch in enumerate(board_array) if ch == '.')
>>> pos2d = tuple(row for row in zip(*[iter(pos1d)] * 4))
>>>
>>> # Remove the .'s if you want.
>>> board_array = [ch if ch != '.' else ' ' for ch in board_array]
>>>
>>> def populate(board, num_q, avail):
...     """ Places num_q Q's at positions randomly selected from 
        avail. Taken positions are removed from avail."""
...     pos_a = sample(avail, k=num_q)
...     for p in pos_a:
...         board[p] = 'Q'
...         avail.remove(p)         # Remove the taken position from avail.
...         
>>> avail = list(pos1d)  # List of available squares (or position indices).
>>>
>>> populate(board_array, 4, avail) # Place 4 Q's randomly.
```

We now have a randomly populated board.

```
>>> print_board(board_array)
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   | Q |   | Q |
+---+---+---+---+
| Q |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | Q |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

If you want a board with larger squares. This will produce larger squares. The number of squares wide and high can also be dynamically specified.

```
>>> def board(x, y):
...     b = (('+' + '-----+' * x + '\n') +
...         (('|' + '     |' * x + '\n') +
...          ('|' + '  .  |' * x + '\n') +
...          ('|' + '     |' * x + '\n') +
...          ('+' + '-----+' * x + '\n')) * y)
...     return list(b)
```

The position lists, `pos1d` and `pos2d`, make it easy to index into the board array and place characters at the position we want.

```
>>> def place_q(board, row, col):
...     pos = pos2d[row-1][col-1]
...     board[pos] = 'Q' # or '\U0000265B'
>>>
>>> place_q(board_array, row=3, col=2)
```

`pos1d` is useful for randomly selecting a position to put a Q.

```
>>> q_pos = random.choice(pos1d)
>>>
>>> board_array[q_pos] = 'Q'
```

Comment: how should the placement of q be decided if we call a random function which generates the position

Comment: `from random import randint; grid_array[pos[randint(0,3)][randint(0,3)]]` @mukhtarali

Comment: can i mail u my prog @todd

Comment: there's pastebin unless you don't want others to see it (?) @mukhtarali

Comment: My example has features that could be used to construct a simple game. I should get at least one upvote for that =/